# How fast should 6 liters flow out of the sink through a 6cm pipe?

Tags: water, everyday-life

I had 6 liters in the sink when I pulled the plug. It took the water about 30 seconds to get through a pipe which has about 5cm in diameter. I think the pipe might be blocked a bit, causing it to have at some point a smaller diameter.

Now I wondered: If the pipe was clean (nothing blocking it), how fast should the water be gone?

Comment: That's a seriously difficult problem to model. The outcome depends on many factors and is mathematically hard to predict. Here's an example of a simpler derivation (without pipe!) for a similar but simpler problem: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/velocity-of-efflux.868030/. Considering the math difficulty, it would be advisable to unblock the pipe and *measure* the new emptying time!

Comment: @Gert I will try to unblock the pipe anyway ;-) However, I just wondered if I can get an estimate of "how blocked" it is.

Comment: Even the *shape and nature* of the blockage would affect the reduction in flow. So if the blockage free time was 15 s, one could still not say "oh, so it was half-blocked!". In physics terms that would be meaningless. For a better understanding of flow here, I suggest to study Torricelli's Law, Bernoulli's Principle and Darcy-Weisbach equations.

Comment: @Gert Oh? Assuming that the pipe would be cylindrical, going down all the time, I thought it would be as simple as getting the smallest diameter of the pipe? (At least approximately)

Comment: @sammygerbil: *"However, surely it is not difficult to estimate the ideal flow rate of water in a vertical pipe of 5cm diameter - if we also know the length."* Unfortunately not. We're dealing with *transient* flow here, because the water level in the sink constantly varies. That makes the calculation much harder, as the link I provided shows.

Comment: unfortunately we don't *a priori* know what the blockage looks like.

Comment: Initially I agreed with Gert : this problem has too many unknowns, and could be solved far more easily and more appropriately by experiment. However, surely it is not difficult to estimate the ideal flow rate of water in a vertical pipe of 5cm diameter - if we also know the length?

Comment: @Gert : Sorry, I deleted my comment, trying to form it into an answer.  I agree there are transients, I just wondered about a ballpark figure, making reasonable assumptions  such as that the pipe is much longer than the depth of the sink, that flow is laminar etc.  But I got 1700 litre/s!  Far larger than 6/30=0.2 litre/s

Comment: @sammygerbil: yes, it's probably turbulent flow, to make matters worse. It should still be possible to make some estimates but is it really worth the trouble? ;-)

Comment: @Gert : I agree.  Time to pull the plug one this one!

Comment: http://www.lmnoeng.com/Tank/TankTime.php

Comment: I suggest that you use this site. You really need not be bothered by the varying height of the water column as it is averaged out in the integration that you perform over there. As far as turbulent flow is concerned, you could always approximate it to stream-lined flow. Otherwise, you could consider the surface roughness and make corrections to the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the complexities, a simple back-of-the-envelope calculation gives you a flow rate of $0.71$ liters per second, meaning your pipe is around $72\%$ blocked.

Assuming a typical area of the kitchen sink to be $22$ by $30$ inches ($4484 \ cm^2$), 6 liters ($6000\ cm^3$) of water would be $1.33\ cm$ high from the base of the sink.

[image]

Instead of looking at water as a fluid, if you consider it as a system of particles at rest, its center of mass is then $h_{com}=0.669\ cm$ high from the base and would have a P.E of $mgh$. Now you pull the plug, the particles flow through the hole, and their P.E becomes K.E. At the moment when the center of mass passes through the hole,
$$\dfrac{1}{2}mv_{com}^2=mgh_{com}$$
$$v_{com}=\sqrt{2gh_{com}}=36.2\ cm\ s^{-1}$$

Note that even though the velocity of water flowing at any moment is time-varying and depends on the geometry of the sink etc, the average velocity would be somewhere around $v_{com}$. Not an exact calculation, but still a reasonable approximation.

Plugging in the area of the hole to be $\pi\times(5/2)^2=19.63\ cm^2$, the flux turns out to be $710.8\ cm^3\ s^{-1}$ or $0.71$ liters per second. But since you are only getting $0.2$ liters per second flux, effectively $72\%$ of the hole's cross-sectional area is clogged.